# Foreach changed row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreach

I'm trying to manipulate my MySQL results to create an XML file. This question is not to do with the latter part of that task, but the former: manipulating the SQL query results in PHP.

I want to create a foreach statement which will group the results into the column value they share ('group_id'). (I might have three rows with the same column value, and five rows with another column value.)

I imagine having one foreach construct inside another one. The parent one should loop through the results by the shared column value ('group_id'), and the second should loop through based on another column ('message_content').

This is a suggestion of my data (actual data, here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ce52/1):

```
message_id |  group_id  |  message_content  |  group_name

1          |  1         |  ........         |  ........
2          |  1         |  .......          |  .......
3          |  1         |  ......           |  ......
4          |  2         |  .....            |  .....
5          |  2         |  ....             |  ....
6          |  3         |  ...              |  ...
7          |  4         |  ..               |  ..
8          |  4         |  .                |  .
```

This is a suggestion of my PHP code. (Remember, I'm trying to construct an XML file based on the data.)

```
foreach ($results['group_id'] AS $group)
{
   // <group_name>

   foreach ($results['message_id'] AS $message)
   {
      // <message_content>

      // <message_content>
   }       

   // </group_name>
}
```

Comment: Rather than do this in the PHP you should let the database do the heavy lifting by getting the data out that you want with a properly formed query. Can you show the table structure or maybe set up a http://sqlfiddle.com?

Comment: your suggestion won't work. you're looking the SAME data structure in both loops, and would produce an `n^2`-sized output.

Comment: Sounds like your SQL needs an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: I have included my table structure, and the query I'm using, here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ce52/1  I have just considered the results would need to be ordered by "last_message_date", but still be returned as groups. @JayBlanchard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use an`ORDER BY` clause in your SQL query to order by the `group_id`, then something like this should achieve what you want;

```
$groupId = null;
foreach ($results as $message) {
    if ($message['group_id'] !== $groupId) {
        if (!is_null($groupId)) {
            echo '</group>';
        }
        echo "<group id=\"{$message['group_id']}\">";
        $groupId = $message['group_id'];
    }
    echo "<message id=\"{$message['message_id']}\">{$message['message_content']}</message>";
}
if (!is_null($groupId)) {
    echo '</group>';
}
```

Comment: That works for me, thanks. Would the final echo display more than one <message> within the <group>? At the moment, only one <message> (row) is displayed.

Comment: Erm, not sure exactly what you mean, but having just looked at this answer again, I've realised there's no final closing `</group>` tag, I'll update my answer to fix that. Is this what you mean?

Comment: It's difficult to explain without posting a code block of expected output, but within each `<group>` tag, there might be multiple `<message>` tags. At the moment, only a single `<message>` tag appears . I don't think this is because of my SQL statement, because I have executed that elsewhere to view the result. The first foreach tag is working as expected (for the groups), but only one `message` is being echoed.

Comment: Hm.. that is odd, looking over this code, I can't think how you'd get that behaviour. Looking at the SQL fiddle you've provided, I notice there's no `group_id` field, presumably that's actually the `conversation_id`. Have you made sure to change that field in both places that the code references `group_id`? (the comparison on line 3 and the assignment on line 8)

Comment: I discovered it was my SQL statement which was the cause of only one child being displayed. Thanks for your help with this.